# Creating an authenticated XA resource from ActiveMQConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-transactions, spring-jms, xa, atomikos, activemq-artemis

I have an Apache ActiveMQ Artemis (1.3) instance to which I'm trying to connect from a standalone Spring (4.3.2) application my team is currently working on. It has Spring *JTATransactionManager* using Atomikos (4.0.4) *UserTransactionManager* as a provider and during those transactions I need to connect to several resources, including the aforementioned MQ. Following Artemis and Atomikos manuals we've set up *ActiveMQConnectionFactory* which then gets passed to *AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean*. It all happens in a Spring container but that doesn't seem to be related to our problem.

It all worked well until I tried to add authentication to the MQ connection. One can set *user* and *password* properties on an instance of *ActiveMQConnectionFactory*, however, they seem to be taken into account only when creating an ordinary connection:

```
@Override
public Connection createConnection() throws JMSException {
  return createConnection(user, password);
}

@Override
public Connection createConnection(final String username, final String password) throws JMSException {
  return createConnectionInternal(username, password, false, ActiveMQConnection.TYPE_GENERIC_CONNECTION);
}
```

Atomikos is calling *createXAConnection*() method (from *XAConnectionFactory* interface) which, as I see in its implementation, disregards the credentials unless explicitly passed:

```
@Override
public XAConnection createXAConnection() throws JMSException {
  return createXAConnection(null, null);
}

@Override
public XAConnection createXAConnection(final String username, final String password) throws JMSException {
  return (XAConnection) createConnectionInternal(username, password, true, ActiveMQConnection.TYPE_GENERIC_CONNECTION);
}
```

This is the way a few other methods in this class work as well, therefore I assume it's not a bug. If so, how should I obtain an authenticated *XAConnection*? I don't see the possibility of Atomikos calling the overloaded version, looking at its code.

Regards,
Jakub

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we've decided to wrap *ActiveMQConnectionFactory* in a class implementing the necessary interface:

```
public class ActiveMQConnectionFactoryWrapper implements XAConnectionFactory {

  private final ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory;

  public ActiveMQConnectionFactoryWrapper(ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
  }

  @Override
  public XAConnection createXAConnection() throws JMSException {
    return factory.createXAConnection(factory.getUser(), factory.getPassword());
  }

  @Override
  public XAConnection createXAConnection(String userName, String password) throws JMSException {
    return factory.createXAConnection(userName, password);
  }

  @Override
  public XAJMSContext createXAContext() {
    return factory.createXAContext(factory.getUser(), factory.getPassword());
  }

  @Override
  public XAJMSContext createXAContext(String userName, String password) {
    return factory.createXAContext(userName, password);
  }
}
```

Other interfaces could be implemented as well, if needs be.